# What is maximum depth of Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, depth

I saw on the Firebase [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) that the limits for the "Maximum depth of subcollections" is 100.

Does this refer to the number of sub-collections that one collection can have in total? Like `/collection/document/sub1/document`, `/collection/document/sub2/document` all the way up to `/collection/document/sub100/document`?

Or does this refer to it in the way that would make the file path longer? For instance: `/collection/document/sub1/document/sub2/document/.../sub100/document`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this refer to the number of sub-collections that one collection can have in total?

No, it does **not** refer to the number of sub-collections that one collection can have in total, it refers to the number of subcollections that you can add in-depth, which is up to 100.

> Or does this refer to it in the way that would make the file path longer? For instance: `/collection/document/sub1/document/sub2/document/.../sub100/document`?

Yes, that's the correct approach.

Please also note, that Firestore is as fast as it is at level 1 is also at level 100.

Comment: I wonder who would nest so deep....